c++ downcast to unknown derived class inside function which takes pointer to base class
I have code with a lot of data classes 'CustomData1' ... 'CustomDataN' with different structure but with the same base class 'DataBase'. Some another class 'Controller' should process data passed to 'doSomething()'. But I need to downcast pointer from base to unknown derived class and invoke correct function for it.
Example code like this:
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

// base class
class DataBase
{
public:
    DataBase()
    {
    }

    virtual ~DataBase()
    {
    }

    // method to get derived class pointer (downcast)
    virtual DataBase* getPtr() = 0;
};

template<class T>
class DataAny : public DataBase
{
public:
    DataAny()
        : DataBase()
    {
    }

    virtual ~DataAny()
    {}

    // downcast to derived class
    T* getPtr() override
    {
        dynamic_cast<T*>(this);
    }
};

class CustomData1 : public DataAny<CustomData1>
{
    int _i;
public:
    CustomData1()
        : DataAny<CustomData1>()
        , _i(1)
    {
    }

    int i()
    {
        return _i;
    }
};

class CustomData2 : public DataAny<CustomData2>
{
    std::string _s;
public:
    CustomData2()
        : DataAny<CustomData2>()
        , _s("something")
    {
    }

    std::string s()
    {
        return _s;
    }
};

class CustomData3 : public DataAny<CustomData3>
{
    double _d;
public:
    CustomData3()
        : DataAny<CustomData3>()
        , _d(10.0001)
    {
    }

    double d()
    {
        return _d;
    }
};

class Controller
{
public:
    Controller()
    {
    }

    virtual ~Controller()
    {
    }

    bool doSomething(DataBase* data)
    {
        if (data == nullptr)
            return false;
        auto ptr = data->getPtr();

        // I want to avoid this
        auto d1 = dynamic_cast<CustomData1*>(data);
        if (d1 != nullptr)
        {
            return process(d1);
        }
        auto d2 = dynamic_cast<CustomData2*>(data);
        if (d2 != nullptr)
        {
            return process(d2);
        }
        auto d3 = dynamic_cast<CustomData3*>(data);
        if (d3 != nullptr)
        {
            return process(d3);
        }
        // ...
        //auto d100 = dynamic_cast<CustomData100*>(data);
        //if (d100 != nullptr)
        //{
        //    return process(d100);
        //}

        // and make one universal function call but compilation error here
        process(data);

        return false;
    }

private:
    bool process(CustomData1* data1)
    {
        std::cout << "CustomData1 i=" << data1->i() << std::endl;
        return true;
    }

    bool process(CustomData2* data1)
    {
        std::cout << "CustomData2 s=" << data1->s().c_str() << std::endl;
        return true;
    }

    bool process(CustomData3* data1)
    {
        std::cout << "CustomData3 d=" << data1->d() << std::endl;
        return true;
    }
};


int main()
{
    // make data
    auto obj1 = std::make_unique<CustomData1>();
    auto obj2 = std::make_unique<CustomData2>();
    auto obj3 = std::make_unique<CustomData3>();

    Controller contr;
    contr.doSomething(obj3.get());
    contr.doSomething(obj2.get());
    contr.doSomething(obj1.get());
}

I don't want to make a lot of 'if' with dynamic_cast because can be a lot of data structures. I need method in base class 'getPtr()' which downcast to correct derived class or somehow invoke needed function 'process()' with needed derived class.
How to make it correct? What pattern exists in this case? I am tried type erasure pattern but not really understand how to use it in my case.

IIRC, the only way to override virtual DataBase* getPtr() is by doing virtual DataBase* getPtr() {your definition goes here} ... override keyword is recommended but not a must and not T* getPtr(). What will happen here is that T* can create a function like MyClass getPtr() and that most surely is NOT AN override.

You may want to look at the visitor pattern.

@PeteBecker hmm... but the OP is doing T* getPtr(). If I pass in a random class, will that still be considered an override?

@PeteBecker, no, you're right, I'd forgotten all about covariant return types (A year in LISP... and I forget all about the joy of C++ :D). On a side note, the OP should Ideally enforce the constraint of the template type being that of a derived class...

Just a noob guess. Does this help: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern

@ph3rin you are right, visitor pattern helps, thank you. But I guess how to make it through pointers, how to downcast to derived class?
